# How to sort a dictionary based on a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
a = {'ground': obj1, 'floor 1': obj2, 'basement': obj3}
```

I have a list.

```
a_list = ['floor 1', 'ground', 'basement']
```

I want to sort dictionary a using its keys based on the list. Is it possible to do that?

i.e.:

```
sort(a).based_on(a_list) #this is wrong. But I want something like this.
```

The output doesn't have to be another dictionary, I don't mind converting the dictionary to tuples and then sort those.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The naive way, sorting the list of (key, value) tuples, using the [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and a custom sort key (called for each `(key, value)` pair produced by `dict.items())`):

```
sorted(a.items(), key=lambda pair: a_list.index(pair[0]))
```

The faster way, creating an index map first:

```
index_map = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(a_list)}
sorted(a.items(), key=lambda pair: index_map[pair[0]])
```

This is faster because the dictionary lookup in `index_map` takes O(1) constant time, while the `a_list.index()` call has to scan through the list each time, so taking O(N) linear time. Since that scan is called for each key-value pair in the dictionary, the naive sorting option takes O(N^2) quadratic time, while using a map keeps the sort efficient (O(N log N), linearithmic time).

Both assume that `a_list` contains *all* keys found in `a`. However, if that's the case, then you may as well invert the lookup and just *retrieve the keys in order*:

```
[(key, a[key]) for key in a_list if key in a]
```

which takes O(N) linear time, and allows for extra keys in `a_list` that don't exist in `a`.

To be explicit: O(N) > O(N log N) > O(N^2), see [this cheat sheet for reference](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

Demo:

```
>>> a = {'ground': 'obj1', 'floor 1': 'obj2', 'basement': 'obj3'}
>>> a_list = ('floor 1', 'ground', 'basement')
>>> sorted(a.items(), key=lambda pair: a_list.index(pair[0]))
[('floor 1', 'obj2'), ('ground', 'obj1'), ('basement', 'obj3')]
>>> index_map = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(a_list)}
>>> sorted(a.items(), key=lambda pair: index_map[pair[0]])
[('floor 1', 'obj2'), ('ground', 'obj1'), ('basement', 'obj3')]
>>> [(key, a[key]) for key in a_list if key in a]
[('floor 1', 'obj2'), ('ground', 'obj1'), ('basement', 'obj3')]
```

Comment: @Martjin - this has solved one of my problems, but I'm having some trouble understanding where the `pair` in `index_map[pair[0]]` comes from / is derived. It could only come from the `a.items()` tuples, but the link between that and `pair` isn't clear (yet). Know where I could look for a detailed explanation / more examples of what's going on here?

Comment: @rong: it is exactly that, the `(key, value)` pair produced by `dict.items()`. The `sorted()` function passes *each element being sorted* to the `key` callable, and for `dict.items()` the elements are always tuples with two objects, the key and the value.

Answer (score 13):

You could just retrieve the values in order of the keys provided by the list and make a new list out of the key-value pairs.

Example:

```
d = a      # dictionary containing key-value pairs that are to be ordered
l = a_list # list of keys that represent the order for the dictionary
# retrieve the values in order and build a list of ordered key-value pairs
ordered_dict_items = [(k,d[k]) for k in l]
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
a = {'ground': 'obj1', 'floor 1': 'obj2', 'basement': 'obj3'}
a_list = ['floor 1', 'ground', 'basement']
ordered_dict = {}
for item in a_list:
    ordered_dict[item] = a[item]
print(ordered_dict)
{'floor 1': 'obj2', 'ground': 'obj1', 'basement': 'obj3'}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Its great that it works for you, but it would help us if you could explain what you did and how did you solve the initial problem!

Comment: Simple and best!